# How to get Mac to give Ethernet connection priority?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, ethernet

I have the following issues / question. I use WIFI and Ethernet through each other like most people probably.

Certain things like ripping a blu ray I want to do through the Ethernet connection so that is when I plug it on.

However, I first have to turn WIFI off to "force" the mac to choose to route the data through the Ethernet connection.

In system settings under network / priorities I have the proper order, so Thunderbolt Ethernet above WIFI.

Any idea how I can make the Mac use the Ethernet cable without turning off the WIFI? THANKS!

Comment: Why do you need both?  Are you on seperate networks?  Just out of curiosity, how do you "rip a blu ray through the Ethernet?"

Comment: When I rip a blu Ray I do this directly to my NAS. With a gigabit Ethernet connection this is much faster. That is what I meant. Cheers.

Comment: Alain, I now also read the other post. I think I have to rephrase. The question basically is that I have the correct priority settings. When I am on wifi and plug the Ethernet also on it is not used in the same (speedy) way as Ethernet alone. The speed difference is huge. What can cause this and what to do to solve other than my own workaround of simply turning off wifi?

Comment: I am still not clear on what you are trying to do.  Is WiFi and Ethernet on the same network?  If so, why?

Comment: Yes, on the same network. I would expect everybody to do this the same way not? You just walk around the house using wifi and when higher speed is needed you plug in the Ethernet. Why is the Mac not following the priority list as of that moment?

Answer (score 25):

**According to Apple Support:**

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Network.
2. Click the Action pop-up menu , then choose Set Service Order.
3. Drag a service, such as Ethernet, to the top of the list.
4. Click OK, then click Apply to make the new settings active.

Full article is [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18458).

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I already had this done so Ethernet is on top of wifi in the priority settings. However it feels a bit that if you start a connection or a share or so with wifi it will not use Ethernet when that is enabled after wifi.

Comment: @Arnoud Ah! My bad.

Comment: This didnt work for me. Ethernet is still at the top of the list, (has been by default) yet it's using the wifi as the main source of internet.

Comment: Feb 2019 running macOS 10.14.3 and this still doesn't work.  None of my Macs will prioritise ethernet unless I turn off wifi, and if I do that I lose the ability to unlock my Mac with my Apple Watch.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. Changed order, ran speedtest and got 600 MBps, so that went through the wire. Locked my mac and it unlocked with my watch, which requires Wifi. Now whether it can access the printer on Wifi upstairs - haven't tried that yet.